# I want to import a variable from another python file(Django)

Tags: python, django

I have an apps.py file in Django project where I have written some and I want to import a variable from there to another file.

[image]

I want to import archive variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load something once when the server starts, put that code that loads the file in the apps.py file.

For this problem to import the "archive" variable also got solved when I removed the function and just used the single line in the class.

[Code that I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10FHv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can import your class and access `archive` value like;

```
from your_module.apps import PredictConfig

archive = PredictConfig.startup()
```

but you have to `return` value in your method;

```
@staticmethod
def startup():
    check_for_gpu(-1)
    archive = load_archive("{}/utils/model.tar.gz".format(HOME), cuda_device=-1)
    return archive
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering but the thing is, with this method in apps.py, I am trying to avoid reloading again and again of the file in the load_archive method after every request. So I want to confirm that the solution will not reload the file again and again when called. Will it?

Comment: With the solution you provided, every time a request is made, the file has to load and since that file is large in size, it takes a lot of time. So, instead of that function, I only wrote the code to load to file in the class and that also solved the problem of importing that variable.